# Champagne 2 get_channels() on a non-object

Tags: 2.7.0, champagne

I'm running EE 2.7 and running champagne 2.3.4 (which is the latest).  When I went to change my email template in the extensions section I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_channels() on a non-object in [system_path]/expressionengine/third_party/champagne/ext.champagne.php on line 188
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some hunting and found that ee 2.6 and I assume 2.7 doesn't load the channel_model automatically.  So I added this line right above 188:

```
$this->EE->load->model('channel_model');
```

so 188 and 189 look like this:

```
'channels' => $this->EE->load->model('channel_model'),
'channels' => $this->EE->channel_model->get_channels()->result_array(),
```

and that fixed my problem.